# Add attribute to multiple created entities with same id pattern

Tags: fiware-orion

I didn't found in documentation or source code the specifications to add attribute to multiple created entities with same id pattern. Only found the method for add attr to entity one by one (with array), but [this method](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/user/append_and_delete/index.html) doesn't work (lazy method) when need add attribute to 100+ entities with id pattern (idIot:1, ... , idIot:N).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NGSIv2](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) method that allows to update several entities at once is `POST /v2/op/update`. It uses as parameter an array of entities:

> `entities`, an array of entities, each entity specified using the JSON entity representation format (described in the section "JSON Entity Representation").

and in the cited "JSON Entity Respresentation" section we have:

> An entity is represented by a JSON object with the following syntax:
>
> - The entity id is specified by the object's `id` property, whose value is a string containing the entity id.
> - The entity type is specified by the object's `type` property, whose value is a string containing the entity's type name.
> - Entity attributes are specified by additional properties, whose names are the name of the attribute and whose representation is described in the "JSON Attribute Representation" section below. Obviously, id and type are not allowed to be used as attribute names.

Thus, in conclusion, you cannot use a pattern of entities to update.

However, this has an easy workaround: you can create a script (or logical function in a wider program) to do that work, basically:

- To query Orion with a given pattern, getting a set of entity (taking into account pagination, if the number of entities is large).
- To update all these entities with `POST /v2/op/update` (taking into account doing it in batches, as there is a limit of 1MB in Orion request, if the number of entities to update is large).

You can have a look to [this script](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/utils/delete_attribute_by_query.py), which works in this way (although in this case is to delete a set of entities instead of updating an attribute).